# Percentage calculation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

I am trying to figure out the win-loss/accuracy of stock trades exported to excel.  I have thousand of lines of trades.  Unfortunately the software exports the win/loss as a fraction and not two separate numbers.  The only thing I can do is divide the cell with the win/loss, in this example I end up with 1.25/1.00. Is there any way to obtain a win/loss percentage from the available data (#trades and win/loss fraction)?  I need to somehow end up with 55.55% (5/9) and 50% (5/10)

No. Trades............Win/Loss...............%

9..............................5/4......................???

10............................5/5......................???

I don't know if this is the appropriate forum but figured I would ask since I've been trying to figure it out for an hour.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: What you need is 
$$ \frac{{\rm Win/Loss}}{1+{\rm Win/Loss}}\times 100\% $$

---

Let the fraction you're given be $f,$ and the number of trades be $n,$ and the number of win be $w,$ We know that
$$ f = \frac{w}{n - w}$$
In other words
$$ 1/f = \frac{n-w}{w} = \frac{n}{w} - 1 \\
 \frac{n}{w} = 1/f + 1 = \frac{1+f}{f}$$
Now you can compute the desired ratio $w/n$ simply as
$$\boxed{ w/n = \frac{f}{1+f}}$$

Comment: Examples: $(5/4)/(1+ 5/4) =  55.56\%$ and $(5/5)/(1+5/5) = 50\%$

Comment: $ \text{TL;DR}$ (+1)

Comment: Awesome you saved me hours of work!  Example was key.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want this:

No. Trades...................Win/Loss...................win%

9..............................5/4......................100*5/9

10.............................5/5.......................100*5/10

**(W+L)..............W/L..................100*W/(W+L)**